# How to run interactive busybox shell inside initramfs so that it's PID=1

Tags: linux, shell, initramfs, busybox

#### Background

I need to assemble my own initramfs and before writing its init script I want to do all the required operations by hand, i.e. from an interactive shell. My choice is statically linked busybox for all operations.

#### What I do

I have busybox executable in initramfs /bin, symlink for shell in /bin: 'sh' -> /bin/busybox, and in initramfs root, init symlink to /bin/sh

#### What I get

The busybox thinks now that its name is `init` and gives me a prompt `Please press Enter to activate this console.` After I press Enter, I get into the shell, but its PID is not 1. A process that has PID=1 is `init`.
Because of this I can't manually execute `switch_root` and continue with booting main system.

I tried to run bash as shell in initramfs and succeeded: it runs with PID=1 and allows execution of `switch_root`.

#### Question

From initramfs, how can I run interactive busybox shell with PID=1?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**TLDR Answer**

You can do this by simply symlinking `init` program to your shell of choice, in the initramfs, as you already discovered.

**"Busybox" problem**

The problem you are facing is a busybox "feature". Busybox packs all the utilities it has selected to contain at compilation into a single universal executable. It then starts "sub-utility" on execution based on it's symlink name, i.e. `argv[0]` vector.

This technique allows it to have all the utilities statically linked-in (no dylibs aka DLLs are needed - making it very robust - broken libc (like glibc) will never make your busybox not work - yet it allows it to share compiled code common among ebbeded utilities as if they were split into exes and dylib and referenced by those, as all utilities live in a single executable and thus all can call same shared functions directly (like `strlen`, `printf` etc.) - i.e. code of functions within executable is shared among all the sub-utilities as if it was living in a DLL) and save storage space (you just need a single busybox binary, which contains all the utilities/commands in a single file, thus all the utilities share same ELF header and other ELF format structures and are simply a functions of that executable - making the overall result smaller as dozens of separate executables: symlinks take less space on the device than multiple ELF structures of multiple utility executables would take).

Now, busybox determines sub-utility to run, let's say `ls`, by either seeing `["busybox", "ls"...]` or by seeing `["ls",..]` at zeroth position of it's argv vector when execd.

Ie `ln -s busybox ls ; ./ls` is equivalent to running `busybox ls` which is equivalent to running `ls`, if previous symlink is placed correctly (i.e. in $PATH).

As your symlink is named `init`, that gets passed by kernel into the busysbox's `argv[0]` vector and that is what busybox "sees" as name it was invoked with and thus starts as actual `init` program sub-utility.

**Solution**

To fix this, this could maybe work:

- create text file `/bin/init`
- mark it executable
- make it's code the following:

```
#!/bin/sh
exec /bin/sh # this should replace current init process which is the sh interpreter from shebang above but with arg[0] of `init` with sh interpreter with argv[0] of `sh` - and this should be enough, to make busybox believe it should run `sh` sub-utility, which will end as PID1 because of `exec` in front.
```

In a nutshell you must persuade busybox it's running as a process named `sh` for it to act like shell.

In my experience, when developing ad-hoc iniramfses and init schemes it's much more productive to have `/bin/init` point to your actual init implementation and define 2 bootloader menus instead:

- menuitem 1: boot with my init
- menuitem 2: boot with shell, by adding `init=/bin/sh` as LAST parameter to the kernel command line

This way you can simply pick the mode in which to boot (testrun, manual) by selecting wished menuitem from booloader/qemu etc..